# Problem with validation form with Angular 7 and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

i can´t make my form work correctly 
the problem when i put my the validation the form i can´t make login work
if remove the validation the login system work like charm
i have this errors

(node:9664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
    at app.post (F:\Projecto\GestStocks\Server\index.js:23:41)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:9664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9664) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:9664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
    at app.post (F:\Projecto\GestStocks\Server\index.js:23:41)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:9664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

this is my code

```
ngOnInit() {
var runLoginValidator = function() {
var form = $('.form-login');
 var errorHandler = $('.errorHandler', form);
      form.validate({
        rules : {
          username : {
            minlength : 4,
            required : true
          },
          password : {
            minlength : 8,
            required : true
          }
        },
        submitHandler : function(form) {
          errorHandler.hide();
          //form.submit();
        },
        invalidHandler : function(event, validator) {//display error alert on form submit
          errorHandler.show();
        }
      });
    };
  runLoginValidator();

}

loginuser(event){
  event.preventDefault();
const target = event.target
const username= target.querySelector('#username').value
const password= target.querySelector('#password').value
this.Auth.getUserDetails(username,password).subscribe(data =>{
  if(data.success){
this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)
  }else{
    window.alert(data.message)
  }
})

}
  <form class="form-login" (submit)="loginuser($event)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-icon">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username">
              <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-actions">
            <span class="input-icon">
              <input type="password" class="form-control password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
              <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
              <a class="forgot" href="#forgot">
                I forgot my password
              </a>
             </span>
          </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
              Login <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
            </button>
          </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When working with Angular, it is recommended that you follow Angular's recommended approach for validation ... *not* JQuery. Angular provides two techniques for form management/validation: template-driven forms and reactive forms. You can read more about them here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation    I have examples of both template-driven and reactive forms validation here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms (See `Demo-Start`for template-driven forms and `Demo-Final` for reactive forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really use jQuery with Angular, it's bad practice.

Your login for should look like the following:-

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
  <input placeholder="Username" type="text" formControlName="username">
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password">
  <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
</form>
```

You should also really be using Angular form controllers when creating a form:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
    });
  }

  login() {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
    let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
    let password = this.loginForm.value.password;
  }
}
```

This should work for you, you will need to update the login() function.

For more information look at [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

You will also need to add in the styles you have on your form.

Comment: i have this error Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. (" <!-- start: LOGIN BOX --> <div class="box-login"> <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()"> <input placeholder="Username" type="text" formControl"): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@8:12

Comment: You need to import FormsModule & ReactiveFormsModule into your imports in your app.module.ts file.

Comment: how get value from my form and i want to send  this code this.Auth.getUserDetails(username,password).subscribe(data =>{
    if(data.success){
  this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
  this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)
  //sdsadad
    }else{
      window.alert(data.message)
    }
  })
    console.log();

Comment: I have updated my answer with the username and password available as variables.

Comment: thanks for the help i have change all code where i use jquery i using bootstrap and i using  theme and this theme uses alot of jquery

Comment: Jquery can cause security issues in your application depending on how it’s being used. If my answer resolved you issue, please accept it by clicking the tick next to the answer. This will help people resolve the same issue faster in the future.

Comment: i can´t make the make the validation if password math

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for. You can create custom validators please have a look at https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/ In your original question there wasn't any math checking in your password validation. If this is a new issue please start a new question.